# Autowire beans by interface but exclude specific bean at injection time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm currently injecting a list of Spring `@Component`  which all implement the same interface. This works fine however I want to inject this same list into an instance of a bean in that list so I can act on all the other beans in that list. I can't see how to exclude a specific bean from that injection, I can filter the list after injecting it but this of course results in a Spring circular dependency exception at startup. My question is can I at the point of injecting tell spring to exclude the class being injected to from the list of beans?

```
public interface Foo {
    String doSomething();
}
```

```
@Component
public class Foo1 implements Foo {

    private final List<Foo> foos;

    public Sample(final List<Foo> foos) {
        //Don't include Foo1
        this.foos = foos;
    }

    public String doSomething() {
        foos.forEach(foo -> foo.doSomething());
        return "aString";
    }
}
```

```java
@Component
public class Foo2 implements Foo {

    private final List<Foo> foos;

    public Sample(final List<Foo> foos) {
        //Don't include Foo2
        this.foos = foos;
    }

    public String doSomething() {
        foos.forEach(foo -> foo.doSomething());
        return "anotherString";
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class Foo3 implements Foo {
//and so on
```

Comment: You want to inject list of beans of some type X into a bean of type X without including the latter in the list or you want to do something with beans of type X, excluding some bean of type X, before the bean is also included in the list?

Comment: The former, inject list of beans of interface X into Class Y that also implements interface X but exclude Y from that list of beans

Comment: However in say class Z that implements interface X then I want to inject the list of beans of interface X but exclude Z from that list of beans

Comment: use an `ObjectProvider<Foo>` and use that instead of the `List`. When needed use the `stream()` method to either do something with each or first filter the ones you need.

Comment: This looks like an anti-pattern, why would you ever want to do something like this?
It looks like, from each implementation of Foo, you want to trigger the doSomething method of all the other implementations, that would cause an infinite loop, and would not make sense. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

This solution is pretty much a hack, and I would not recommend using it unless really necessary. Instead of declaring `Foo2` as a component you can define it inside a `@Configuration` class by
injecting [ListableBeanFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory.html) as a parameter in the bean definition method and then using it's `getBeansOfType` method to filter out the implementations of `Foo` that you actually need to instantiate the `Foo2` bean.

So your Foo2 class would look like

```
public class Foo2 implements Foo {

    private final List<Foo> foos;

    public Foo2(final List<Foo> foos) {
        this.foos = foos;
    }

    public String doSomething() {
        foos.forEach(foo -> foo.doSomething());
        return "anotherString";
    }
}
```

And the configuration class would look like

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    Foo2 foo2(ListableBeanFactory bf) {
        final Map<String, Foo> fooBeans = bf.getBeansOfType(Foo.class);
        List<Foo> foos = // filter out what you don't need from fooBeans
        return new Foo2(foos);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of injecting a list in the constructor, you can look up all beans of type `Foo` in the `doSomething` methods, and then exclude the current one. To look up, use any of the methods from [BeanFactoryUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactoryUtils.html), like `beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors`, and then exclude `foo1`, which is the bean name for class `Foo1`. The look up can even be coded into a default method in interface `Foo`.